# Renaming K9 Mail package name

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am having a lot of trouble renaming K9 mail's package name. I am modifying it and would eventually like to put it on the market but i can not do that if i cannot rename it. I have tried using refractor and the ADT tool in eclipse in different combinations. I am able to get the program to launch after i use the refractor and ADT together, but when i start activities outside the main activity the program forecloses. In refractor I have been selecting all of the check boxes other than the box about non java files. Has anyone been able to rename K9 Mail before? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I can link anyone willing to help to the source I am trying to rename.

Comment: Why don't you just contribute your ideas and code to the K9 project?

Comment: I am modifying it for a specific purpose. I work at a college and I am attempting to slim it down and make it work only on IMAP and require no extra setup information(servers, ports, ssl...) other than the students email and password. This will save the IT department a lot of time and save the students the hassle of configuring an email client. The modification I am making would not do much for the overall project, though i have the source listed on the Google code page.

Comment: I response a similar question in this post, try with it: [rename-k9-package-name][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26637464/2903697

Answer (score 1):

There's a k9 shell script (which requires perl) specifically for this purpose: tools/build-beta. should work in a cygwin environment if on windows. it requires a bit more modification if changing the domain of the package, as well. i've modified it to a more general sense, though. it runs with the same command as ant (i.e. "sh tools/build-beta debug"), and temporarily renames everything and then puts it back. you need to change the first 5 lines, and you'll need to uncomment a couple of lines if changing the TLD from com to edu. everything below `ant $@` reverses the process. i don't know anything about eclipse.

alternatively, you could ask us to enter your university as an auto-configurable account.

```
BETA_TLD=com
BETA_DOMAIN=fsck
BETA_PROJECT=k9
BETA_PROJ_NAME=K9
BETA_APP_NAME="K9 Mail"
BETA_PACKAGE="${BETA_TLD}.${BETA_DOMAIN}.${BETA_PROJECT}"
BETA_PATH="${BETA_TLD}/${BETA_DOMAIN}/${BETA_PROJECT}"
perl -pi -e"s|\@string/app_name|$BETA_APP_NAME|g" AndroidManifest.xml
perl -pi -e"s|com/fsck/k9/R.java|$BETA_PATH/R.java|g" build.xml
perl -pi -e"s|LOG_TAG = \"k9\"|LOG_TAG = \"$BETA_PROJECT\"|" src/com/fsck/k9/K9.java
find src/com/fsck res -type f |xargs -n 1 perl -pi -e"s/com.fsck.k9(?=\W)/$BETA_PACKAGE/g"
perl -pi -e"s|com.fsck.k9|$BETA_PACKAGE|g" AndroidManifest.xml
mv src/com/fsck/k9 src/com/fsck/${BETA_PROJECT}
mv src/com/fsck src/com/${BETA_DOMAIN}
#mv src/com src/${BETA_TLD}
perl -pi -e"s|K9|$BETA_PROJ_NAME|g" build.xml
ant $@
#mv src/${BETA_TLD} src/com
mv src/com/${BETA_DOMAIN} src/com/fsck
mv src/com/fsck/${BETA_PROJECT} src/com/fsck/k9
perl -pi -e"s|$BETA_PACKAGE|com.fsck.k9|g" AndroidManifest.xml
perl -pi -e"s|$BETA_PATH/R.java|com/fsck.k9/R.java|g" build.xml
find src/com/fsck res -type f |xargs -n 1 perl -pi -e"s/$BETA_PACKAGE(?=\W)/com.fsck.k9/g"
perl -pi -e"s|LOG_TAG = \"$BETA_PROJECT\"|LOG_TAG = \"k9\"|" src/com/fsck/k9/K9.java
perl -pi -e"s|$BETA_PROJ_NAME|K9|g" build.xml
perl -pi -e"s|$BETA_APP_NAME|\@string/app_name|g" AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: Your answer seems like it could really help me out if you could explain it further. I am not sure how to run an ANT script. I tried to run it as a perl script in Cygwin and in Ubuntu. Both gave me errors. I tried to go through the source manually and change every occurrence of com.fsk.k9 to the package name I needed. After doing this the .apk launches and I can view my mail and edit settings, but I cannot compose mail. The application force closes at that point. I'm not sure what i'm missing.