# Custom K9 package name

Tags: android, android-studio, renaming

i am writting you cause i am not finding any solution.

I've just downloaded K9 source code from github and it compiles succesfully and when i install it in my android device, i set up an email account and i go to one whatsapp conversation, and send the conversation via email, k9 works out of the box.

The problem comes when i try to do exactly the same but trying to rename the whole Android studio package name of all k9 project. then if i install it in my android device and configure my email account, it works but when i try so send whatsapp conversation via email, k9mail is not in the list of email applications.

Is there any solution to this issue? I am getting crazy.

Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, i've just tried Perl script wich is described in this post without success: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926898/renaming-k9-mail-package-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the actual name of k9 mail package: `com.fsck.k9` and add extra name after de k9 string: `com.fsck.k9.your-package-name`

If you use grandle you can do it with this option: in file `build.gradle` includes this code:

```
defaultConfig { 
     applicationId 'com.fsck.k9.your-package-name'
}
```